# How can I create a Membership Payment with the Order API?

Tags: civimember, api, contributions

I have a script that is (among other things) a workaround for a bug in CiviSEPA extension. For this workaround, I need to create a Membership Payment to connect an existing Membership with an existing Contribution. Without this workaround, the contribution is not mapped into the membership.
At the moment, I am using the following code to do this:

```
$createMembershipPayment = civicrm_api3('MembershipPayment', 'create', [
                'membership_id' => $membershipID,
                'contribution_id' => $contributionID,
            ]);
```

I get the following warning from this:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Not having valid line items for membership payments is invalid. 
Caller: CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::updateMembershipBasedOnCompletionOfContribution in
 xxx/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php on line 1111
```

I assume that I should rewrite the script to the Order API using Line Items, so I can get rid of this warning. Is that correct?

In the documentation about Order API, I couldn't find anything about MembershipPayments.
Additionally, the documentation says: "The Order API is intended to be used as the primary API for adding, updating, and deleting orders. When using the Order API you should: Rely on the Order API to create related objects like line items, memberships and event registrations. (Don't pre-create them)".

I don't have the option to **not** pre-create Memberships and Contributions. The task of the script is only to connect those two entities with each other.
Is there a way to create only a Membership Payment with Order API, connecting existing Membership and Contribution?